How to build a type from another type and make mypy checking work
I'm working with Python's type hinting system and I'm trying to create a type alias for a function that's similar to an existing function type, but with one additional argument. Here's what I've attempted:
from typing import Callable

# Original function type
RK_function = Callable[[float, int], int]

# Attempted new function type with an additional int argument
RK_functionBIS = Callable[[*RK_function.__args__[:-1], int], int]

I expected RK_functionBIS to represent Callable[[float, int, int], int], which it does when runned directly without checking it with mypy. However, when I run mypy for type checking, I get this error:
text

error: Invalid type alias: expression is not a valid type
[valid-type] Q


The construction happens at runtime; mypy doesn't try to "evaluate" *RK_function.__args__[:-1] during type-checking.

ok thanks. Is there a similar way to do the same thing but not at runtime. I don t want to define 2 time fast the same function type. (to spare time and avoid forgetting to update the second function type if I change the first one)

I don't think so. Python lacks the tools to build types from smaller parts except in a few special cases (e.g., using ParamSpec).

As of today, Python doesn't support direct extraction of a Callable alias's arguments for use in another type. However, if your code snippet is representative of the problem you're solving, then your RK_functions look like they're completely made of positional-only parameters, so you can at least refactor out the arguments part. See mypy Playground:
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing_extensions import Unpack, TypeAliasType

RK_function_args = TypeAliasType("RK_function_args", tuple[float, int])

# Original function type
RK_function = TypeAliasType("RK_function", Callable[[Unpack[RK_function_args]], int])

# Attempted new function type with an additional int argument
RK_functionBIS = TypeAliasType("RK_functionBIS", Callable[[Unpack[RK_function_args], int], int])

>>> bis: RK_functionBIS
>>> res: int = bis(1.0, 2, 3)  # OK
>>> bis("1.0", 2, 3)           # Error: first argument should be float
>>> bis(1.0, 2)                # Error: not enough arguments


Hi @dROOOze your method works but it is the old generic syntax (before pythong 3.13) I tried with the new one but it failled. I think you could be interested by the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79292914/why-does-unpacking-with-the-new-generic-syntax-in-python-3-13-cause-a-mypy-error

exactly same code  than dROOOze but I added a concrete value for bis
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import TypeAliasType,Unpack

RK_function_args = TypeAliasType("RK_function_args", tuple[float, int])

# Original function type
RK_function = TypeAliasType("RK_function", Callable[[Unpack[RK_function_args]], int])

# Attempted new function type with an additional int argument
RK_functionBIS = TypeAliasType("RK_functionBIS", Callable[[Unpack[RK_function_args], int], int])

def ff(a: float, b:int,c:int)-> int:
    return 2

bis: RK_functionBIS =ff
res: int = bis(1.0, 2, 3)  # OK
print(res)

